# How to figure out the country of a device connected to AWS IoT Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, country, aws-iot-core

Hey Stackoverflow crowd,

does anybody know a mechanism on how to identify the country in which a device connected to AWS IoT core is located? Is it possible to get this information out of the box or do I need to implement this manually by storing the country information in an attribute when provisioning the device?

Thanks a lot and best regards
The Smart Home Maker

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean on getting information out of the box,- I don't know about any possibility to detect country in AWS IoT core without adding this information manually.

There are at least two ways how you can achieve this:

- As you mention - save this information in attribute on device. But this can be not very handy if you manage some dynamic installations of devices as example,- in case of changing location every device should be updated (and not all devices can store this).
- Example that we using in our solution - Enrich event on the fly by AWS IoT Core rule and DynamoDB. Here the idea is:

  - every device can be identified by MAC or SN as example (we setting this to topic name).
  - DynamoDB with device list (indexed by SN or MAC) - which is holding information you want to add to event.
  - AWS IoT core rule that getting every incoming event, on the fly requestion dynamoDB for additional info using [get_dynamodb()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html#iot-sql-function-get-dynamodb), adding this to event and follow with action (as example republish to different topic).

Comment: Thank you for your detailled response! So I guess there is no other way of dealing with the issue than annotating the device with attributes OR by enriching an event on the fly. If there is not any other idea posted within the next days, I will mark your response as the accepted answer. THANKS A LOT